# Rx Js - create an observer for $.ajax Complete()

Tags: ajax, reactjs, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an ajax call for an insert operation. I need to update a grid (future there might be many) once the ajax call completed. How to do this using Rx Js.

I have done something with event based but it won't work out for my case.

NOTE: save ajax call is in different script file.

```
var submitButton = document.querySelector('.btn-primary');
var refresh1ClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(submitButton, 'click');
var requestStream = refresh1ClickStream.startWith('startup click')
    .map(function () {
        var max = 10;
        return 'http://localhost/.../GetPayments';
    });
var responseStream = requestStream
    .flatMap(function (requestUrl) {
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(requestUrl));
    });


function createSuggestionStream(closeClickStream) {
    return closeClickStream.startWith('startup click')
        .combineLatest(responseStream,
            function (click, data) {
                return data;
            }
        )
        .merge(
            refresh1ClickStream.map(function () {
                return null;
            })
        )
        .startWith(null);
}

var paymentStream = createSuggestionStream(refresh1ClickStream);
//var pfaStream = createSuggestionStream(refresh1ClickStream);

// Rendering ---------------------------------------------------
function renderSuggestion(payments, selector) {
    //render grid
}


paymentStream.subscribe(function (payment) {
    renderSuggestion(payment, 'payment1');
});

//pfaStream.subscribe(function (pfa) {
//    renderSuggestion(pfa, 'tblPayFromAccount');
//});
```

Comment: So what part of this example is not working?

Comment: this is working for the click event of submit button but I want this to be worked once the insert of that click event has completed (ajax call). something like I want a listener to the ajax complete() method and once its calls the complete my payments grid should populate.